# Return true or false from if statements in model to use afterwards in view

Tags: php, joomla3.0

Im using a MVC and I have the following function in my model:

```
public function subscribirUser(){
    $item_id = JRequest::getCmd('id');
    $user_id = JFactory::getUser()->id;

    //Coger todos los campos del cupon
    $db = $this->getDbo();
    $query = 'SELECT * FROM #__k2_items where id='.$item_id;
    $db->setQuery($query);

    $resultado = $db->loadObject();

    //Insertar el cupon como suscrito
    $query = 'INSERT INTO #__cuphoneo_subscripcion (user_id, item_id, fecha, estado) VALUES ('.$user_id.', '.$item_id.', now(), 1)';
    $result = $db->setQuery($query);
    $db->query();
    //Sacamos los valores de los campos extra
    $campos_extra = json_decode($resultado->extra_fields); 

    foreach($campos_extra as $value){ 
        if($value->id == 4){ 
            $num_max_cup_descargar = $value->value;
            $num_max_cup_descargar = $num_max_cup_descargar - 1;
            $value->value = $num_max_cup_descargar;
            $campos_extra_updated = json_encode($campos_extra);
            $query = 'UPDATE #__k2_items SET extra_fields=\''.mysql_real_escape_string($campos_extra_updated).'\' WHERE id='.$item_id;
            $db->setQuery($query);
            $db->query();
        }

        if($value->id == 8){ 
            $num_max_cup_desc_user = $value->value;

            $query = 'SELECT count(item_id) as contador FROM #__cuphoneo_subscripcion WHERE item_id='.$item_id.' AND estado=1';
            $db->setQuery($query);
            $resultado = $db->loadResult(); 

            if($resultado == $num_max_cup_desc_user){

            }
        }

        $fechaHoy = date("Y-m-d");

        //Comprobamos si la fecha de validez es igual a la fecha de hoy
        if($value->id == 12){
            if($value->value == $fechaHoy){
                $query = 'UPDATE #__k2_items SET publish_down=DATE_ADD("'.$fecha.'", INTERVAL 2 DAY) WHERE id='.$item_id;
                $db->setQuery($query);
                $db->query();
            }
        }

        //Comprobamos si la fecha de validez es igual a la fecha de hoy
        if($value->id == 23){
            if($value->value == $fechaHoy){
                $query = 'UPDATE #__k2_items SET publish_down=DATE_ADD("'.$fecha.'", INTERVAL 2 DAY) WHERE id='.$item_id;
                $db->setQuery($query);
                $db->query();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to return true or false within each if so I can later use these to validate a button in my view. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can probably store them in multi dimentional array like:

```
$a = array();
foreach($campos_extra as $k=>$value){ 
    if($value->id == 4){ 
        $num_max_cup_descargar = $value->value;
        $num_max_cup_descargar = $num_max_cup_descargar - 1;
        $value->value = $num_max_cup_descargar;
        $campos_extra_updated = json_encode($campos_extra);
        $query = 'UPDATE #__k2_items SET extra_fields=\''.mysql_real_escape_string($campos_extra_updated).'\' WHERE id='.$item_id;
        $db->setQuery($query);
        $a[$k] = $db->query();
    }

    if($value->id == 8){ 
        $num_max_cup_desc_user = $value->value;

        $query = 'SELECT count(item_id) as contador FROM #__cuphoneo_subscripcion WHERE item_id='.$item_id.' AND estado=1';
        $db->setQuery($query);
        $resultado = $db->loadResult(); 

        if($resultado == $num_max_cup_desc_user){

        }
    }

    $fechaHoy = date("Y-m-d");

    //Comprobamos si la fecha de validez es igual a la fecha de hoy
    if($value->id == 12){
        if($value->value == $fechaHoy){
            $query = 'UPDATE #__k2_items SET publish_down=DATE_ADD("'.$fecha.'", INTERVAL 2 DAY) WHERE id='.$item_id;
            $db->setQuery($query);
            $a[$k] = $db->query();
        }
    }

    //Comprobamos si la fecha de validez es igual a la fecha de hoy
    if($value->id == 23){
        if($value->value == $fechaHoy){
            $query = 'UPDATE #__k2_items SET publish_down=DATE_ADD("'.$fecha.'", INTERVAL 2 DAY) WHERE id='.$item_id;
            $db->setQuery($query);
            $a[$k] = $db->query();
        }
    }
}
```

here are stored in array $a